# Is it an antipattern to call WEBAPI services from MVC Controllers?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

If it was decided to use WebAPI to create a service layer to be used for a variety of clients.  What would be the best way to architect the web client?

As WebAPI is web-friendly it would be possible to consume this directly from the client using javascript.  However I would worry that this can get messy fairly quickly and javascript is not the easiest technology to unit test.

An alternative would be to use the HttpClient class to call the REST services from MVC controllers.  Is this a valid approach?

I suppose that the two approachs above could be combined but I would worry that this would get messy.  Would you agree that it would be better to go with one approach or the another?

Sorry I have seen many posts on whether to use WebAPI or MVC but none on combining the two.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you already have an MVC project in your application and you are trying to extract out service layer from it?

Comment: No this is a greenfield project.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> An alternative would be to use the HttpClient class to call the REST
>   services from MVC controllers. Is this a valid approach?

Yes, absolutely. It's just that this code should not be put in your controllers but rather in your DAL layer, because controllers should not know where the data comes from (flat file, database, Web API, ...).

So there are 2 approaches:

- You decide to consume your Web API from your MVC client application using the HTTP protocol. In this case you create an implementation for your repository (DAL layer) that will use the HTTP client and return directly the domain models
- You decide to directly consume the services contained in this Web API without sending HTTP requests. In this case you reference the assembly containing the service layer for your Web API in your MVC client application and directly this assembly becomes the service layer for your MVC application. In this case the Web API through HTTP serves for other clients: javascript, mobile, ...

Which approach you choose would really depend on your specific scenario and requirements. Do you need to support interoperable clients other than your MVC client application? In any case start by defining a service layer in a separate assembly containing your domain models and stuff. Then you could always expose this service layer through a Web API (or a WCF service or whatever) or directly reference it from .NET clients.

Comment: Regarding 2nd approach, how would this be implemented? Unclear about creating an instance of the webapi to call the instance methods, as it seems like a similar problem you have when calling controller action methods directly(rather than using RenderAction), as the controller expects it to be instantiated from the MVC framework(for various contextual information such as HttpRequest.Current, Principle, etc.). So instantiating a webapi class from a MVC controller and calling the method directly, the request doesn't go through the webapi pipeline, so I'd expect there'd be more to this?

Comment: Not challenging you, just trying to visualize what this approach would look like.  I remember with WCF, if you were calling a WCF service from another process on the same machine, you could use named pipes+binary serialization for much better performance. Do you know of anything like this for WebAPI?

Comment: @AaronLS, ASP.NET Web API was designed for creating RESTful web services. In the REST world there's no such notion as named pipes and binary serialization.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an MVC project and you are trying to separate out the api operations from the MVC project into a separate web api project? If that's the case you have to weigh the benefits before jumping and creating a separate service project.

Once you created a separate web api project then you can't easily consume the service methods straightly from javascript in your MVC project because of cross-domain barrier (of course there are JSONP and CORS but they don't make things so easy), so you have to rely on the `HttpClient` class creating unnecessary wrapper methods in your controllers to communicate with the service.

It is worth to think having the api stuff in the same MVC project when you have views that needs data provided by your api methods, but only thing is you have to use `ApiController` instead of `Controller`.