# call web api from normal web mvc in same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a web MVC app that contains normal MVC controller and web api controller.

WHat is proper way to call web api controller from normal MVC controller action in same project?

Comment: Don't.  Instead, move it to a separate class.

Comment: this web api controller is only used exclusively by normal web controller so it's the reason I put them in one project.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 3):

ASP.Net Web API is meant to be called over HTTP, not from your server-side logic. Perhaps your rendered presentation can call your web API via a client-side request (ajax, for example).

If you find yourself in a position where your MVC controller's action needs to execute code that is only available in a Web API action, then you should consider decoupling that code from your Web API and moving it into a more platform-agnostic area of your code (service layer?).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a way to send JSON (or similar) back to the client you can simply choose to return something else than a view from your MVC controller. Then it's all handled within your MVC web app and you don't need to use Web API.

```
public JsonResult DetailsJson(int id)
{
    Car car = carRepository.Find(id);
    return Json(car, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This example would then be called using

```
/Cars/DetailsJson/3
```

Please not that GET is allowed in the sample (by adding JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) for test reasons and may be removed if you only want to support POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

See [Is it an antipattern to call WEBAPI services from MVC Controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502901/is-it-an-antipattern-to-call-webapi-services-from-mvc-controllers)

In a nut shell, use an httpclient in order to get to your api.